# How to return manytomanyfield as object in Django RestFramework API

Tags: python, json, django, list, django-rest-framework

I tried to create an API with Django RestFramework, so i created 2 models Note and Task and have a ManyToManyField in Note model so i can put many Task in a Note but the API i created don't return full object feature but just the id. Here is my code:

```
class NoteAPI(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
```

Here is my models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.task

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default="B")
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task, related_name="note_task", blank=True)
    process = models.IntegerField( default=0, validators=[max_int_value])
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title + " is "+ str(self.process) + "% completed"
```

And i want the out put can looks like:

```
 [
    {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Sleep",
            "priority": "F",
            "detail": "Don't do it, stay awake and do your job",
            "completed": false,
            "process": 0,
            "task": [
                      {
                         "id": 1,
                         "task": "Go to bed",
                         "completed": false
                      },
                     {
                         "id": 2,
                         "task": "Start counting",
                         "completed": false
                      }
                    ]
     }
 ]
```

But it actually be like this

```
 [
    {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Sleep",
            "priority": "F",
            "detail": "Don't do it, stay awake and do your job",
            "completed": false,
            "process": 0,
            "task": [
                      1,
                      2
                 ]
     }
 ]
```

So what i can do to have the out put like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `NoteSerializer` how to serialize `Task` objectcs.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("id", "task", "completed")


class NoteSerializer(models.Model):
    task = TaskSerializer(many=True)
```

You probably also want to prefetch tasks to keep the number of DB queries to minimum.

```
class NoteAPI(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    queryset = Note.objects.prefetch_related("task").all()
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. It took me all afternoon just to find this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh sorry, i think that my reputation have to reach 15 to vote.